# ubuntu 17.10 wont install any package from terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 17.10

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10, so when i try to install a package for example i want to install Brackets

```
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xdman
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do these?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Comment: yes i just say for example brackets my problem is on xdman installation

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets,  i want this for xdman